# Android sqlite - "No such table" while table exist

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wrote a SQL query to return items to show to the users.
However, there seems to be a weird problem with it.

Here's the error:

```
11-17 13:44:08.644: E/AndroidRuntime(3229): Caused by: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: events (code 1): , while compiling: 

SELECT eventsmeta.*, events.* FROM eventsmeta JOIN 
(SELECT events.*, classes.* FROM events JOIN classes ON events.idfortype=classes._id)
 ON eventsmeta.eventid=events._id WHERE (eventsmeta.repeat_start = ?) OR 
(((? - eventsmeta.repeat_start) % (eventsmeta.repeat_day * 86400000)) = 0) OR 
(((? - eventsmeta.repeat_start) % (eventsmeta.repeat_week * 7 * 86400000)) = 0) OR 
((((12 - eventsmeta.repeat_start_month + ?) % (eventsmeta.repeat_month)) = 0) AND (eventsmeta.repeat_start_year <= ?)) 
ORDER BY events.startat ASC;
```

The thing is the table `events` does exist (I verified it with a database viewer).

If so, I guess there is some syntax problem... but I can't find it.

**Other questions about this problem** suggested the code refers to a different database, or a not up-to-date one. I do not think that is the problem since I tried to delete and recreate the database from scratch. I've also used the same code pattern before without any problems...

**If so, what else could cause this problem?**

### `CREATE TABLE` Code

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE_EVENTS = 
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Events.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
    Events._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
    Events.COLUMN_NAME_EVENT_PRIORITY + " INTEGER," + //
    Events.COLUMN_NAME_EVENT_TITLE + " Text," +
    Events.COLUMN_NAME_START_AT + " INTEGER," +
    Events.COLUMN_NAME_END_AT + " INTEGER," +
    Events.COLUMN_NAME_EVENT_NOTES + " Text," +
    Events.COLUMN_NAME_EVENT_TYPE + " Text," +
    Events.COLUMN_NAME_ID_FOR_TYPE + " INTEGER);";
```

### Extra Code

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SchooLauncherDbHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();

String sql = SQL QUERY HERE;

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {.............});
```

### Edit

Apparently, `SELECT * FROM events` works perfectly...

### Edit 2

`SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
public class SchooLauncherDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static SchooLauncherDbHelper mInstance = null;
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SchooLauncher.db";
    String query;
    String[] iconFileNames = {};

    public static SchooLauncherDbHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SchooLauncherDbHelper(
                    context.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mInstance;
    }

    private SchooLauncherDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_SEMESTERS);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_STUDENTS);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_SUBJECTS);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_STUDENTSTUBJECTJOIN);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_TEACHERS);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_TEACHERSUBJECTJOIN);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_CLASSES);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_TEACHERCLASSJOIN);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_ASSIGNMENTS);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_EXAMS);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_EVENTS);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_EVENTS_META);
        db.execSQL(SchooLauncherContract.SQL_CREATE_SETTINGS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i("onUpgrade()", "Upgrading from " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please re-check if you created the database or table and also check if any spelling mistakes available of naming the database or table.

Comment: Both the database and the table exist (I checked it with the file explorer plugin in eclipse). There also shouldn't be any spelling mistakes since in the real code I use the same variables that I used to create the table.

Comment: Can we see your SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: Try again with DATABASE_VERSION = 2

Comment: Mmmm... not sure I see the problem that you cite... but I see others.  You are going to call SQLiteOpenHelper from the UI thread: it better not do anything non-trivial.  Also, you gain very little by caching the OpenHelper: it caches the DB instance for you.  ...any you'll need to be sure getInstance is called from a single thread.  Have you tried printing the query and running it from a shell?

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Ahh, didn't mention the whole query is being executed from inside an `AsyncTask`. As for the shell... I'm afraid I'm not that advanced yet. Could you please elaborate about the problem withe getInstance?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem!

All I had to do is make an alias for the derived table, and use it instead of `events`:

```
SELECT eventsmeta.*, E1.* FROM eventsmeta JOIN 
(SELECT events.*, classes.* FROM events JOIN classes ON events.idfortype=classes._id) AS E1
 ON eventsmeta.eventid=E1._id WHERE (eventsmeta.repeat_start = ?) OR 
(((? - eventsmeta.repeat_start) % (eventsmeta.repeat_day * 86400000)) = 0) OR 
(((? - eventsmeta.repeat_start) % (eventsmeta.repeat_week * 7 * 86400000)) = 0) OR 
((((12 - eventsmeta.repeat_start_month + ?) % (eventsmeta.repeat_month)) = 0) AND (eventsmeta.repeat_start_year <= ?)) 
ORDER BY E1.startat ASC;
```

I think that the problem was I couldn't possibly select the table `events` neither from the `eventsmeta` table and the new derived table because it didn't exist **THERE**. So I had to create a temporary new "table" - E1, and use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

this problem occur some times, the solution is to uninstall your application from the device and then install again.

Comment: Basically the purpose of what you offered to do is for the app to recreate the database. I have already done that as I said in the post... I still re-installed it just to be safe, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: That's a work-around, not a solution. If that tends to happen in production, customers will demand your head on a plate.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution is to uninstall your application then run again.**

Reason - you may have changed the `@Override onCreate()` method of SQLite class.

we cannot change the tables of SQLite by changing the onCreate code. That's what happened to me.

**TIP - **  We have to delete the already created SQL database to make changes directly or you can use sql code to that.